# undefined reference to symbol '_ULx86_64_step' libunwind.so.8: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

Tags: linux, command-line, caffe, glog, libunwind

I'm trying to compile Caffe.

```
make all -j4
```

worked fine. But making the tests is giving the following error.

Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie) 64-bit

```
g++ --version
g++ (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2
```

Gives this error on

```
make test -j4

caffe$ make test -j4
CXX/LD -o .build_debug/test/test_all.testbin src/caffe/test/test_caffe_main.cpp
LD .build_debug/src/caffe/test/test_solver.o
LD .build_debug/src/caffe/test/test_platform.o
LD .build_debug/src/caffe/test/test_tile_layer.o
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libglog.a(utilities.cc.o): undefined reference to symbol '_ULx86_64_step'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//libunwind.so.8: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:609: recipe for target '.build_debug/test/test_platform.testbin' failed
make: *** [.build_debug/test/test_platform.testbin] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libglog.a(utilities.cc.o): undefined reference to symbol '_ULx86_64_step'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//libunwind.so.8: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:609: recipe for target '.build_debug/test/test_tile_layer.testbin' failed
make: *** [.build_debug/test/test_tile_layer.testbin] Error 1
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libglog.a(utilities.cc.o): undefined reference to symbol '_ULx86_64_step'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//libunwind.so.8: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:609: recipe for target '.build_debug/test/test_solver.testbin' failed
make: *** [.build_debug/test/test_solver.testbin] Error 1
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libglog.a(utilities.cc.o): undefined reference to symbol '_ULx86_64_step'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//libunwind.so.8: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:597: recipe for target '.build_debug/test/test_all.testbin' failed
make: *** [.build_debug/test/test_all.testbin] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the cmake method to make Caffe seems to have solved this issue for now.